# Multiple Runtime Permissions - Only Requesting First One

Tags: android, permissions

I am trying to request multiple permissions at the start of my application, but only one of the permissions is being asked and then the screen freezes up. I am attempting to ask for: `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `CAMERA`, and `BODY_SENSORS`.

The thing that baffles me is that I started this application only asking for read and write permissions, and it would ask for them and that's that, the rest of the app would run smoothly, but after adding these other two the app would freeze.

Side note: It is kind of annoying but the way I do permissions is I ask for them right away, so it is still a white screen when the app opens and the permissions popup comes up. After accepting read/write permissions the app freezes and stays on this white screen. Also, I most definitely also added the permissions into my manifest.

I am going to include what one of my permission calls looks like, because all the rest are practically the same, just changing which permission is needed. Below I am including what my `CAMERA` looks like:

```
    int permissionCheck3 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

    if(permissionCheck3 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)){
            showExplanation("Permission Needed", "Rationale", Manifest.permission.CAMERA, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA);
        }
    }

    while(permissionCheck3 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        permissionCheck3 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    }
```

I use the code above at the very start of my application in my onCreate right after I assign TextViews, Buttons and other things like that.

```
private void showPhoneStatePermissionCAMERA(boolean displayToast){
    int permissionCheckCAMERA = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    if(permissionCheckCAMERA != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            showExplanation("Permission Needed", "Rationale", Manifest.permission.CAMERA, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA);
        } else {
            requestPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA);
        }
    } else {
        if(displayToast){
            Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "CAMERA Permission (already) Granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

SOME MORE INFO HERE: I have been testing it some more and some interesting things are happening: When I first enter the app, it requests the first permission and then freezes. If I exit the app and re-open it, it requests the second permissions and then freezes, and so on until all the permissions are accepted or denied, then goes on with the application.

Maybe unrelated, but I keep on getting `java.util.zip.ZipException: File too short to be a zip file: 0` one or two times when I hit run before the app starts.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure why your app freezes, so I won't post an answer. But maybe the fact that the Activity is destroyed and recreated after a permission is granted is part of the problem: you ask for the 1st permission, you get it and you ask for the 2nd permission (so you want to start a Dialog which is not part of your app and wait for the result - but maybe the runtime will not show a new Dialog for an app which is being shut down?) Plus you have the while loop, blocking your UI-thread until the permission is granted. Whithout the Dialog (for CAMERA) even showing up, it will loop forever

Comment: @0X0nosugar thanks for the response! I have been trying to play around with it so my application will wait till it receives an answer till it moves onto the next permissions attempt, but I am not having any success. Is there any method you would recommend that would allow me to wait for a response from one until it starts the next? Thanks again

Comment: Each time you request a permission from the user, you'll get the result in `onRequestPermissionsResult()` So at this point you can take the next step, for example request the next permission.

Comment: @0X0nosugar IT WORKED! thank you so much for your help, please post your two comments as questions so I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the fact that the `Activity` is destroyed and recreated after a `Permission` is granted is part of the problem:

you ask for the first permission, you get it and you ask for the second `Permission` (so you want to start a `Dialog` which is not part of your app and wait for the result - but maybe the runtime will not show a new `Dialog` for an app which is being shut down?)

Plus you have the while loop, blocking your UI-thread until the `Permission` is granted. Whithout the `Dialog` (for `CAMERA`) even showing up, it will loop forever.

Each time you request a `Permission` from the user, you'll get the result in `onRequestPermissionsResult()` So at this point you can take the next step, for example request the next `Permission`.